# appending values to create 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a text file with 3240 rows and 1 column of values. Every 81 values represents one layer in a 2-D framework. So after 81 values, I would reach z=2, then 162, z=3 and so forth until then end (should be 40 x levels). I want to append the values in this text file to create a 2-D array, that basically represents a value at a specific (x,z) point. Here's what I have:

```
 df = pd.read_excel("/nfs/home11/grad/2017/et654149/ATM562/HW3/HW3atm562.xlsx")
 pivals=df.as_matrix()
 pi=[]
 l=np.arange(0, 3320, 41)
 count=0
 i=0
 for i in range(len(l)):
         pi[0][i].append(pivals[i])
         count=count+1
```

I keep getting the error "list index out of range" and honestly I have no idea if what I'm trying to accomplish is even correct with the code I am using. Eventually I want to plot this value on a contour filled plot.

Edit: I've tried using reshape before and after the comment below, but I am getting the error "index 40 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1".

Comment: This code works, but I after trying to simply plot this now on a contour plot, I am getting this error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigate a multitude of errors here is a solution:

```
x = 40 
y=81 
z=[[0 for row in range(0,x)] for col in range(0,y)] 
for i in range(x): 
      for j in range(y): 
           z.append(pivals[i+j])
a = array(z)
a = a.reshape(81, 41)
```

Comment: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable is the error I get. Tried putting np.reshape(pivals [81, 40]) and get "index 40 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1".

Comment: All you did was run the code that I provided right? @EliTurasky

Comment: Yes, I simply ran what you provided.

Comment: Try converting the matrix to an array before by using `np.asarray(pivals)` before calling reshape

Comment: The as_matrix already makes pivals an array. That's why in my original comment I tried using brackets instead of parentheses (which I think you are supposed to since it is an array). However, doing this results in the error I posted above.

Comment: `x = 40
y=81
z=[[0 for row in range(0,x)] for col in range(0,y)]
for i in range(x):
         for j in range(y):
             z[i][j]=pivals[i]`

Give the above a shot @EliTurasky, let me know how that goes. I edited my answer to include this as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182375/discussion-between-eli-turasky-and-b-cratty).

Comment: After talking in the chat room, I have updated my answer to the solution we came to a consensus on.